# Mini calendar to control main calendar

Tags: jquery

I am using [arshaw's fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) on my website - I want to have a mini version of this calendar on my admin page that I could use for admin functions. The main calendar for public viewing should have admin functionality disabled.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

this post is old but you can use this

[Full Calender mini-sized](http://wowmotty.blogspot.in/2011/04/fullcalendar-mini-sized.html)